# HTML5 video Tag: Onclick PHP function not getting to the JavaScript: Escaping String

Tags: javascript, php, html, fancybox

I call a function from the "onclick" of a HTML5 video tag inside PHP-

```
      $txt= $row['location'];
      $ext="openFancyBox($txt)";
     <video id="thumbnail" onclick="'.$ext.'" width="320" height="240" controls>
```

The location information I send to the javascript function takes the following format (on inspect element):

```
     onclick="openFancyBox(photos/2014.02.031391434118.mp4)"
```

It never gets into the javascript function, the error from inspect element states-

```
  Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected number
```

I think this is because it is expecting a string format? The file name has to remain this random format.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the code to make the location a string in the JavaScript code. Try this:

```
$ext='openFancyBox("' . $txt . '")';
```